# Redirect output to a file using forfiles

Tags: windows, batch-file, redirect

I want to run a command against a bunch of files in a directory and send the output of the command to a separate `.csv` file for each `.ts` file.

The command I want to run is :

```
ffprobe -print_format csv -show_packet <filename.ts> > <filename>.csv
```

I am trying to script this so it does each `.ts` file in the folder

```
forfiles -s -m*.ts -c"ffprobe -print_format csv -show_packets @FILE > @FILE.csv"
```

If I have the redirect where it is it throws an error in `ffprobe`, if I have the redirect outside of the quotes, it redirects all output to the same file (`@FILE.csv`).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use `CMD /C` if you intend to use redirection:
[forfiles without cmd /c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989312/forfiles-without-cmd-c/26990159#26990159)

```
forfiles -s -m*.ts -c " cmd /c ffprobe -print_format csv -show_packets @FILE > @FILE.csv"
```