# BATch forfiles, command with quotation

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop

So, I'm trying to rescale a bunch of images at once with a program called ImageResizer, and the command `forfiles`.

But since I have to use quotation marks for both, the command itself, and an argument inside of it, that won't work:

```
ERROR: Argument/Option invalid- '4x /save @FILE'.
```

How do I handle those two strings in batch? I found some similar questions, but I didn't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
cd %~dp0
cd gfx
forfiles /s /m *.png /c "C:\Users\Manu\Desktop\NeuerOrdner\ImageRes.exe /load @FILE /resize auto "XBR 4x" /save @FILE"
pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this is a bug in forfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989312/forfiles-without-cmd-c/26990159#26990159).And you need to encode quotes with `0x22`

you can try like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "path=%path%;C:\Users\Manu\Desktop\NeuerOrdner\" 
cd %~dp0
cd gfx
forfiles /s /m *.png /c "ImageRes.exe ImageRes.exe /load @FILE /resize auto 0x22XBR 4x0x22 /save @FILE"
endlocal
pause
```

or

```
@echo off
cd %~dp0
cd gfx
forfiles /s /m *.png /c "C:\Users\Manu\Desktop\NeuerOrdner\ImageRes.exe  /load @FILE /resize auto 0x22XBR 4x0x22 /save @FILE"
pause
```

(additional space after `imageres.exe`)

Answer (score 0):

FORFILES recognizes \" as the way of escaping inner ". So try this:

```
forfiles /s /m *.png /c "C:\Users\Manu\Desktop\NeuerOrdner\ImageRes.exe /load @FILE /resize auto \"XBR 4x\" /save @FILE"
```