# Grep Case Insensitive Not Working

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, grep, case-insensitive

I am working on a fix for a .bat script and there is a problem with the following line:

```
forfiles /m *.site /c "grep -i -l \"%1\^|%2\" %CONFIG_PATH%\\@file" > files.temp
```

For some reason when I  run this in the cmd line (subbing values into 1 and 2) it does not do a case-insensitive search. In a previous version of the file the line was different:

```
grep -i -l "%1\|%2" %CONFIG_PATH%/*.site > %CONFIG_PATH%\files.temp
```

This version works. I cannot figure out why the second one works but the first does not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I do not see why you would even need to use FORFILES at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more digging I found the issue. The issue is not with grep but with forfiles. All I had to do was add an extra space between grep and -i. This is a known bug with forfiles. The in depth reason is in this thread:

[forfiles without cmd /c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989312/forfiles-without-cmd-c/26990159#26990159)

Comment: I think the most general solution (if there is any) for the `forfiles` "feature" is to put the command name twice, like `forfiles /C "grep grep -i ..."`; the double-space might help in this case, but fails for many others...